# "RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo"

Tags: java, android, xml

I am going to create a valentine's app so I have a first    activity(MainActivity) that have a button which activate second Activity(MainActivity 2) the problem is that it says instantiate problem

it says in manifest file

com.example.rajafarid.valentines.MainActivity 2' has no default constructor. 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rajafarid.valentines">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.rajafarid.valentines.MainActivity2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.rajafarid.valentines.DetailActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

main.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends ArrayAdapter<ImageITem> {

private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<ImageITem> data = new ArrayList<ImageITem>();

public MainActivity2(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageITem> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    ImageITem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
}
```

LogCat View

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rajafarid.valentines/com.example.rajafarid.valentines.MainActivity2}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.rajafarid.valentines.MainActivity2 has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.rajafarid.valentines.MainActivity2 has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1641)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1639)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a debbuging service. Please show us some efforts on how did you try to fix the problem.

Comment: #athafoud i don't know how to show.....as  i am newbie in android field...as i can do is above mention if you can help pleasure for me otherwise its okay no problem

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RuntimeException%3A+Unable+to+instantiate+activity+ComponentInfo

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity2 should be extended from Activity

```
e.g. public class MainActivity2 extends Activity
```

By looking at your code it seems you want to create list. If yes, do it in the same activity by implementing custom adapter.

Comment: did that but nothing happens...i want to create a Grid view of images like gallery...it seems problem with the Adapter as you said

Comment: Please check this 2 reference link - http://www.journaldev.com/9538/android-gridview-layout-example-tutorial   https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/05/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-native-android/